# Why the path in the link changes and the transition to this address is not performed?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm new in vue js. And my task is to take data from api, make pagination and when clicking on any post so that a new page opens with more detailed information about the post. I did the pagination, but I can't make the transition. In clicking on the post, the link changes but the transition is not performed. Why the path in the link changes and the transition to this address is not performed?

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/Blog)

Code of main page:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(post, index) of paginatedData" class="post">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id: index} }">
          <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
          <p class="boldText"> {{ post.title }}</p>
          </router-link>
          <p> {{ post.body }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>



  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      current: null,
      page: 0,
      posts: [],
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.getData()
    },
    methods: {
    setCurrent: function(id) {
      this.current = id;
    },
    getData() {
      axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
      })
    },
  }
  }
</script>
```

Code of page to go to:

```
<template>
  <div class="post" v-if="detail">
    <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    data: function() {
      return {
        posts: [],
      }
    },
    created: function() {
      var postId = this.$route.params.id
      this.post = this.posts[postId]
    }
  }
</script>
```

Code of main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'


var Detail = require('./Detail.vue')

Vue.use(VueRouter)

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: 'detail/:id', name: 'detail', component: Detail }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router: router,
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: You need to add a router-view so that matched components are rendered in it.

Comment: Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I already added it where it is possible and where it is impossible) but the code all the same does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all, in your Pagination.vue file you should use the character entity instead of the <etc.

Secondly, the routing change page is rendered, that is, the problem you describe is because you have less <router-view/> component, um, maybe you need to take a good look at vue-router

Finally, I feel that your html semantics and code specifications are poor, so you need to strengthen

i clone u project and run. The code has a lot of bugs

good u lucky
```